# Find the distribution of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Two** dice are tossed. Let $X$ be the random variable which shows the maximum of the **two** tosses.

1) Find the distribution of $X$.

2) Find $P(X\le3)$.

3) Find $E(X)$.

My work so far

1) $P(X=1) = 1/36$

$P(X=2) = 3/36$

$P(X=3) = 5/36$

$P(X=4) = 7/36$

$P(X=5) = 9/36$

$P(X=6) = 11/36$

These results I got following an example with only one dice. I'm not sure if it changes for two dice.

2) I'm not sure how to solve this.

3) $E(X)=4.47$ This result I got following an example with only one dice. I'm not sure if it changes for two.

Comment: Typo aside it looks right.  $P(X\leq 3)$ is just $P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)$

Comment: What typo are you referring to?

Comment: @Koalafications You have $P(X=1)$ twice.  The second should clearly be $P(X=2)$

Comment: PS: The distinction between "*two separate dice thrown at the same time*" and "*two separate throws of the same dice*", isn't relevant for this.  The results of the throws are independent, and we're not interested in order (or placement) of occurrence, merely the maximum of their results.

Answer (score 1):

a) Seems fine. Usually it is arranged in a table, but that probably just superficial.
\begin{array}{r|cccccc}
x&1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
P(X = x)&\dfrac{1}{36}&\dfrac{3}{36}&\dfrac{5}{36}&\dfrac{7}{36}&\dfrac{9}{36}&\dfrac{11}{36}
\end{array}

b) Since the events $X = j$ for $j = 1,2,3$ are disjoint, then
$$P(X\leq 3) = P(X = 1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3) = \frac{1}{36}+\frac{3}{36}+\frac{5}{36} = \frac{9}{36}.$$

c) The expectation is fine.